# Reading apache error logs from php

Tags: permissions, php, apache-httpd

I have apache2 logs at :`/var/log/apache2/error.log`
which has permission:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 127140 Mar 20 12:54 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

for the sake of accessing from php I changed the ownership and group e.g

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 127140 Mar 20 12:54 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

But still I am not able to access the logs as shown below.

*test.php*

```
<?php
 var_dump(exec("/usr/bin/tail -n 10 /var/log/apache2/error.log",$x),$x);
?>
```

*output*

```
string(0) "" array(0) { }
```

My question is how to alter permission to give php process to at-least read the apache logs ? A secure/standard way to access these logs will be much appreciated .

I see following error in error.log

```
/usr/bin/tail: cannot open `/var/log/apache2/error.log' for reading: Permission denied
```

This [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159393/how-can-i-parse-apaches-error-log-in-php) is already asked but solution does not fit in linux environment

Comment: can you show output `ls -ld /var/log/apache2`.

Comment: @Gnouc, forgive me , the issue is resolved now . The trick was using `adm` group http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1318346. Adding `www-data` user to `adm` group and restarting the apache worked like a charm Thanks

Comment: commands were : `sudo usermod -G adm www-data`
  `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: If the issue is resolved, you can post the above comment as answer and accept the same. :)

Comment: yes issue is resolved. I am not sure how much secure that method is. I've to dig in further.

Comment: It seems it will not hurt the system though http://superuser.com/questions/86347/whats-difference-between-group-admin-and-adm . Probably a linux guru might comment